# Phoenix Deployment with EXRM

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

I am trying to deploy a phoenix app on a Ubuntu Server with EXRM.

The release runs perfectly and the website is accessible but when I ping the release it says the

```
Node 'myapp@myhost' not responding to pings.
```

vm.args file

```
## Name of the node
-sname pxblog

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie pxblog

## Heartbeat management; auto-restarts VM if it dies or becomes unresponsive
## (Disabled by default..use with caution!)
##-heart

## Enable kernel poll and a few async threads
##+K true
##+A 5

## Increase number of concurrent ports/sockets
##-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 4096

## Tweak GC to run more often
##-env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 10
```

Updated vm.args (Solved)

```
## Name of the node
-sname pxblog@localhost

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie pxblog

## Heartbeat management; auto-restarts VM if it dies or becomes unresponsive
## (Disabled by default..use with caution!)
##-heart

## Enable kernel poll and a few async threads
##+K true
##+A 5

## Increase number of concurrent ports/sockets
##-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 4096

## Tweak GC to run more often
##-env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 10
```

Comment: Are you pinging from the machine itself (via localhost) or from a different machine?

Comment: yes I am pinging from the same machine.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `vm.args` file.  Look for a line similar to this:

```
## Name of the node
-name test@127.0.0.1
```

I suspect the name you'll find there is "myapp@myhost".  Try changing it to *yourappname*`@localhost` or *yourappname*`@127.0.0.1`.  NB: I do not mean you should put the literal string *yourappname* there.  Substitute the name of your app.

Comment: The vm.args file has this
## Name of the node
-sname appname

Comment: Well then, if I were you, I'd try replacing `-sname appname` with `-name appname@localhost`

Comment: Please add the _exact_ text from your vm.args to the body of your question above.

Comment: tried doing that now it throws an error 
** System running to use fully qualified hostnames **
** Hostname localhost is illegal **

Comment: Hi @RobinSolanki. To mark a question at solved, please click the tick mark adjacent to the answer that most assisted you. Thanks!